# Ionic is possible to use LoadingController from external?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my page I implemented the ionic LoadingController. To show loading dialog I make a method:

```
  public presentLoading(text: string, timeout: number) {
    if (!this.loading) {
      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: text,
        dismissOnPageChange: true
      });
      this.loading.present();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.closeLoading();
      }, timeout);
    }
  }
```

Now it is good, but I also want loading dialog in other pages, but I don`t want to duplicate the code and write again in other pages. I think making a static method which look like this:

```
public static presentLoading(loading: Loading, loadingCtrl: LoadingController, text: string, timeout: number)
```

is ugly. Or the other way:

```
public loading: Loading

constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

public presentLoading(text: string, timeout: number) { ... }
```

Is any other way to create MyLoadingController and instatiate it somehow and inject it in my page?

Comment: what is preventing you from moving the function to a provider and injecting everywhere?

Comment: I am beginner in angular and ionic. If I move the function in a provider will the LoadingController initialized?

Comment: you will just be injecting loadingController in provider.. It will work

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new service called `MyLoadingController`
- Inject loading controller into it `constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }`
- Add your method in there
- Inject new servive where you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Finally I do it. I created CommonLoadingController which extends LoadingController and I added my methods there, and I add it to app.module.ts as a provider. Now I can use it anywhere in constructor.